# How to jump to another HTML page when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying a while to make a game with javascript and html and i wonder is there a way to jump to a another html page when the user clicks on the PLAY button? Also the html page i want to jump to is going to be a loading screen but right now it is just the background of the loading screen. Do you have any tips about making a loading screen? Here is my code so far:

```js
function Game_load() {
  window.location.href = "file:///home/chronos/u-56f297e83910b0d818c1d4b74fa15ed1c727cc9d/MyFiles/HTML,CSS,JS/loadingscreen.html";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://thewallpapers.org/zoom/12916/Vista_Wallpaper_%2811%29.jpg");
}

.button_div {
  text-align: center;
}

.Play_text {
  text-align: center;
  top: 45%;
}

.play_button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.play_button {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.freelogoservices.com/api/main/images/1j+ojl1FOMkX9WypfBe43D6kiP6CqhNGnx7IwXs1M3EMoAJtlSgthPNs8vw8" alt="Logo" width="210" height="140">

<div class="button_div">
  <button onclick="Game_load()" class="play_button"> PLAY </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `title of question` and the question in the `body` do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to clean up a bit of your code. 
Your function `Game_load` should have curly brackets after the init of the function, like that:

```
 function Game_Load(){
     window.location.href = "file:///home/chronos/u-56f297e83910b0d818c1d4b74fa15ed1c727cc9d/MyFiles/HTML,CSS,JS/loadingscreen.html";
}
```